# Как числа из строки записать в массив целых чисел? Числа в строке разделены строго одним пробелом

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть строка, состоящая из четырех чисел и пробелов, как пример -  `"878 57 3 62"`.
Нужно числа из этой строки преобразовать в массив типа `int {878, 57, 3, 62}`

Answer (score 2):

Если вы точно знаете количество чисел (4), то проще всего

```
int a[4]; 
istringstream("878 57 3 62") >> a[0] >> a[1] >> a[2] >> a[3];
```

Если не знаете - то

```
vector<int> a;
istringstream is("878 57 3 62");
copy(istream_iterator<int>(is),
     istream_iterator<int>(),
     back_inserter(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот простой код. После выполнения ответ будет в vector result:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string s;
    s = "123 456 768"; // строка с числами

    vector<int> result = {0}; // инициализация массива

    for (int i = 0; i < (int)s.size(); ++i) {
        if (s[i] == ' ') {
            result.push_back(0); // при пробеле, поймем, что началось новое число
        } else {
            result.back() *= 10; 
            result.back() += s[i] - '0'; // добавили новую цифру числа
        }
    }

    for (int element : result) {
        cout << element << " "; // выводим числа из массива через пробел
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: слышком простой...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan, каков вопрос, таков ответ ¯\_(ツ)_/¯